# Edit Item - Push changes using VSTS library NET6

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to edit a file (gitItem) using VSTS NET6 library.
I am always getting the following error.

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException: TF401028: The reference 'refs/heads/workbench' has already been updated by another client, so you cannot update it. Please try again.
```

It doesn't matter if I create and use other branch, the error is the same.
This is the code of my routine. I believe I am missing something, but really don't know what could be.

The main method is SaveConfigurationFileRepository. I get the item to edit first, to be sure it exists an get its objectId.
I am using changeType = edit , since I want to update the content of an existent item.
Sorry if the piece of code is too large.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;

namespace ConfigurationManager.API.Infrastructure.FileSystem.Context
{
    public class InfrastructureFileContext : IInfrastructureFileContext
    {
        public static FileContextConfiguration? contextConfiguration { get; private set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string ProjctName { get; set; }
        public string RepositoryName { get; set; }
        public string WorkingFolder { get; set; }

        public InfrastructureFileContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            contextConfiguration = configuration.GetSection(FileContextConfiguration.SectionName).Get<FileContextConfiguration>();
        }

        public async Task<int> SaveConfigurationFileRepository(string groupName, string appName, string fileName, string fileContent)
        {
            // Create instance of VssConnection using Azure AD Credentials for Azure AD backed account
            VssConnection connection = new(new Uri(contextConfiguration?.Url), new VssBasicCredential("", contextConfiguration?.AppToken));

            // Get a GitHttpClient to talk to the Git endpoints
            using (GitHttpClient gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>())
            {
                // Get data about a specific repository
                var gitRepository = gitClient.GetRepositoryAsync(contextConfiguration?.ProjectName, contextConfiguration?.RepositoryName).Result;
                GitVersionDescriptor gitDes = new GitVersionDescriptor() { Version = "workbench" };

// Get Item to edit
                var gitItemToEdit = gitClient.GetItemAsync(gitRepository.Id, $"{groupName}/{appName}/{fileName}", versionDescriptor: gitDes, includeContent: true).Result;

                if (gitItemToEdit is not null)
                {
//Create commit objet
                    GitCommitRef newCommit = GetCommitForFile(gitItemToEdit, $"{groupName}/{appName}/{fileName}", fileContent);


//Create refUpdate using gitItem.ObjectId
                    GitRefUpdate refUpdate = new()
                    {
                        RepositoryId = gitRepository.Id,
                        Name = "refs/heads/workbench",
                        OldObjectId = gitItemToEdit.ObjectId
                    };

                    GitPush gitChangesToPush = new GitPush()
                    {
                        RefUpdates = new GitRefUpdate[] { refUpdate },
                        Commits = new GitCommitRef[] { newCommit }
                    };

                    var gitPush = await gitClient.CreatePushAsync(gitChangesToPush, gitRepository.Id);

                    return gitPush.PushId;
                }

            }

            return 0;
        }

        private GitCommitRef GetCommitForFile(GitItem gitItemToEdit, string fileName, string content)
        {
            //Generate Git Commit
            GitCommitRef newCommit = new GitCommitRef
            {
                Comment = "Update configuration template",
                Changes = new GitChange[]
                {
                    new GitChange
                    {
//Also have tried to use Item = gitItemToEdit
                        ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Edit,
                        Item = new GitItem { Path = $"{fileName}" },
                        NewContent = new ItemContent
                        {
                            Content = content,
                            ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            return newCommit;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your error shown, the error might be related to someone else is also updating the branch so that you cannot edit it at the same time. It is recommended that you can create a new branch to test and see whether still meet this error. If the issue still occurs after testing with a new created branch, it might be some error with your data code library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think is solved now.
The issue was on GitRefUpdate.OldObjectId. I was using an GitItem id, now I see it really doesn't make any sense.

GitRefUpdate.OldObjectId has to match with GitRef.OldObjectId.

GitRef defaultBranch = gitClient.GetRefsAsync(gitRepository.Id, filter: branchName).Result.First();

Also, when getting gitItems, path and item name are NO case sensitive.
When pushing changes 'GitItem.Path' IS case sensitive. Be aware of it.

Everything learned from here : [Azure DevOps library samples](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/Git/PushesSample.cs)